# A question on an integral inequality (Cauchy - Schwartz)

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality

In the solution of the problem posed [here](http://www.brand.site.co.il/riddles/201308q.html) , the function $Q(x)=x(x-1)$ suddenly comes out to match the equality condition.

I would like to see the intuition behind the function, as it seems like a magical idea to me that came out from nowhere.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, they are trying to transform the derivative of $p(x)$ onto $Q(x)$. Sure, any $Q(x)$ would do the job but why quadratic function? The reason is simply because you want to take advantage of the assumption that $p(x)$ is a probability density function which integrates to 1, so you really want $Q''$ to be a constant. Then again, why not any quadratic function? I suspect any quadratic function would do the job, but since you are integrating over $[0,1]$, choosing $Q(x)=x(x-1)$ kills the boundary term which simplifies the latter algebra when you are trying to find $p(x)$.